# Error when using "generateActions" comand on CrmSvcUtil.exe

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Error started after updating to CRM 2015. Using the new 2015 SDK, the following command:

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://<organizationUrlName>.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:<outputFilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /namespace:<outputNamespace> /serviceContextName:<serviceContextName> /generateActions
```

Returns the following error:

```
Exiting program with exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of  its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

It asks for Version 6 but if I try to run SDK 2013 I get the same error asking for version 7.

Any idea how to get it to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug inside the CRM 2015 SDK.

Currently you need to use the CrmSvcUtil.exe from SDK 2013 if you run the command against a CRM 2013 instance and the CrmSvcUtil.exe from SDK 2015 if you run the command against a CRM 2015 instance.

Comment: I'm running SDK 2015 against CRM 2015 and getting this error. Opened a service request with Microsoft but no resolution so far.

Comment: I tested a CRM 2015 instance with the 2015 SDK and didn't get any errors. If you have time try with previous SDKs : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4B83260B94D4158!1781&authkey=!APdNJl8zEK9b7to&ithint=folder%2c